# How to create Array of Array in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, arrays, nested

I want to create a nested array or multidimensional array.

In my data is,

```
         FirstName   class   year   dept  lastName
         Bob          MBA    2000   Comp  Smith
         Jack         MS     2001   Comp  McDonald

         NSMutableArray *section = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I want to put my data into the section Array.

Eg:

```
section[0] = [FirstName,LastName];

section[1] = [class, year, dept];
```

So how can i put the values into array like that.
Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your question, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Robin, i am using grouped table view and displayed the data in that section. So i want to split the arrays and stored the values into the single array with different indexes.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a custom data storage class. You could call it `PDPerson.h` You'll also need the .m file. For each property, do something like this:

*In the .h*: Declare each of your properties like so:

```
@interface PDPerson : NSObject{

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *class;//May want to consider renaming
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *year;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *dept;

@end
```

*Then in the .m:*

```
@implementation
@synthesize firstName, lastName;
@synthesize class, year dept;

-(void)dealloc{
    [firstName release];
    [lastName release];
    [class release];
    [year release];
    [dept release];
}
```

Each time you want to create a new "Person" in your array, do this:

```
PDPerson *person = [[PDPerson alloc]init];
```

You can then easily set the properties of the object like so:

```
person.firstName = @"John";
person.lastName = @"Smith";
person.class = @"Math";
person.year = @"1995";
person.dept = @"Sciences";
```

And retrieve them:

```
firstNameLabel.text = person.firstName;
```

The nice thing about these objects is that all you have to do now is add the person object to your array:

```
NSMutableArray *personArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[personArray addObject:person];
```

Comment: sorry guys but I must say: But how much awful is this objective c?? In my language (php) but i guess in most of any other language this would require 3 lines of code not 30 like this answers ... what a bad language...

Comment: @yes123 This is an object oriented concept that I was demonstrating. After he has the class that holds values in place, he only needs the allocation, assignment and array related lines. It's not much more code than PHP, when you think about it. Though there are other major cons with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *section1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1,1", @"1,2", @"1,3", nil];
NSArray *section2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"2,1", @"2,2", @"2,3", nil];
NSArray *section3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"3,1", @"3,2", @"3,3", nil];

NSArray *sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: section1, section2, section3, nil];


int sectionIndex = 1;
int columnIndex = 0;
id value = [[sections objectAtIndex:sectionIndex] objectAtIndex:columnIndex];
NSLog(@"%@", value); //prints "2,1"
```

Be warned, this isn't a flexible way of storing data. Consider using CoreData or creating your own classes to represent the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can just nest multiple NSArray instances within an NSArray.

For example:

```
NSMutableArray* sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray* personsInSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [sections insertObject:personsInSection atIndex:i];
    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfPersons; x++)
    {
        Person* person = [[Person alloc] init];
        [personsInSection insertObject:person atIndex:x];
    }
}
```

This may seem like overkill when coming from languages such as C++ or Java, where multidimensional arrays can be created simply by using multiple sequare brackets. But this is way things are done with Objective-C and Cocoa.