# objective-c accessing arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, ios4, multidimensional-array

I have done the following trying to create 2d and 3d arrays:

```
Array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
Array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
Array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for loop 
[Array1 insertObject:Array2 atIndex:i];
//some code....
[Array2 insertObject:Array3 atIndex:j];
```

im not sure if this is right but every time i loop in my code i add Array2 to a new index in Array1 but im note sure if this works. In other words i hope im not moving the whole array again every time ?!!

Now my problem is that i need to access array2 through looping in array1, then array3 through array2.  I just need to know how to access these arrays using loops so that i can display each array's contents. I need to do something like this array [i][j]
 where "i" for array1 and "j" is for array2

Comment: what are you trin to do dude???

Comment: For what it's worth, please don't start the variable names with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 3d-array (NxMxP):

```
NSMutableArray *array3D = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    NSMutableArray *array2D = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:M];
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        NSMutableArray *justAnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:P];
        [array2D addObject:justAnArray];
        [justAnArray release];
    }
    [array3D addObject:array2D];
    [array2D release];
}
```

Use this creature:

```
[[[array3D objectAtIndex:3] objectAtIndex:4] objectAtIndex:1]; // it's like array3D[3][4][1]
```

Comment: You can simply use `array3D[3][4][1]` will return the objects stored in that location. and is much cleaner and less tedious.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand you properly but if you want to access an array within an array you can use

```
    [[array1 objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j];
```

Pls go through this SO question [How to create Array of Array in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815362/how-to-create-array-of-array-in-iphone)

Is something like this what you need?

**UPDATE**

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",nil];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
NSMutableArray *array3 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
[array3 addObject:array2];
[array3 addObject:array1];
for(int i = 0; i < [array3 count]; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j<[array1 count]; j++)
    NSLog(@"From array3 %@",[[array3 objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j]);
```

Comment: ok i guess you got what i mean yes you are right array within an array. for the example you suggested can you plz show me how i should initialize it ?? or this is how i access my initialization the one i did ?!!

Comment: thanx for the update but i guess its much more complicated than what im looking for and all examples on the web are with predefined objects. i just need to know if i do [array1 addobject:array2] can i still use what you have suggested ??

Comment: See my update it will give you an idea about accessing array within array

Answer (score 0):

Just writing what I have understood...

for accessin the array in loop do 
for loop

```
 NSArray arr = [Array1 objectAtIndex:i] objectIndex:j];
```

will give the the `arr[i][j];`

Comment: ok this is right this what im trying to do, but since i have array2 inside array and doing what you have suggested does the program understand that the second objectIndex:j is for array2 that i have added to array1 ??

Comment: Yes, it understands, because the part in the inner brackets [array1 objectAtIndex:i] gets resolved to "array2". After those brackets are resolved, you're left with the outer brackets: [array2 objectAtIndex:j]

Comment: This is a common question and there are likely many duplicates of it already. You should look for the terms "accessing multi-dimensional arrays in objective-c".